# Google Maps v2 fade-in effects

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

According to this [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-services-40.html) post about `Google Play Services 4.0` it says that you can now do fade-in effects and change if you want to view 3d buildings

`The Maps API enhances map customization features, letting you specify marker opacity, fade-in effects, and visibility of 3D buildings. It’s also now possible to change ground overlay images`

however I dont see anywhere in the documentation that allows you to set any sort of fade-in effects for anything. I assumed they were talking about markers here but I didnt find anything in the markers about this and looked other places too but didnt find anything related to it. so what do they mean with fade-effects and where are they used?

Answer (score 1):

Probably animating opacity of a `Marker` from 0 to 1.

You would do that using `Handler`, to which you send `Message`s / post `Runnable`s every few milliseconds and using [`Marker.setAlpha`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setAlpha%28float%29) with different values.